# Simple holes aren't rendered properly in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a simple rectangular wall and I like to place multiple window holes on it. It always works great for the first hole, but as soon as I add additional holes the polygon becomes messed up. See the images below to see what I'm talking about.

How can I draw holes properly in Three.js?

[image: The right hole is not drawn properly.]

The right hole is not drawn properly.

[image: After increasing the height of the right hole the entire wall mesh becomes halfcut.]

After increasing the height of the right hole the entire wall mesh becomes halfcut.

Here is a sample code that causes above problem:

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo(0, 0);
shape.lineTo(1, 0);
shape.lineTo(1, 1);
shape.lineTo(0, 1);

var windowHole = new THREE.Path();
windowHole.moveTo(0.14999999888241292, 0.7758620689655171)
windowHole.lineTo(0.4999999962747097, 0.7758620689655171)
windowHole.lineTo(0.4999999962747097, 0.3448275862068965)
windowHole.lineTo(0.14999999888241292, 0.3448275862068965)
shape.holes.push(windowHole); 

windowHole = new THREE.Path(); 
windowHole.moveTo(0.5999999955296517, 0.7758620689655171) 
windowHole.lineTo(0.7499999944120646, 0.7758620689655171) 
windowHole.lineTo(0.7499999944120646, 0.6034482758620688) 
windowHole.lineTo(0.5999999955296517, 0.6034482758620688) 
shape.holes.push(windowHole); 

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape), this.material);
root.add(mesh);
```

The above code results in a warning:

Warning, unable to triangulate polygon!
at public_html/libs/three.js:27785

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that this was a bug that is now fixed in version 66dev.
The bug was reported and discussed here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3386

The fixed version that I'm using now is developer built version 66dev committed at Jan 27th, 2014 here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/build

I assume this fix will be merged with the main three.js soon, but until then you can use the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Some code might help. if possible link your code in jsfiddle...

just you need to change the order of the path creation... refer the link...  http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/BuNb2/

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo(-5, -5);
shape.lineTo(-5, 5);
shape.lineTo(5, 5);
shape.lineTo(5, -5);
shape.lineTo(-5, -5);

var windowHole = new THREE.Path(); 
windowHole.moveTo(-2,-2);
windowHole.lineTo(0,-2);
windowHole.lineTo(0,0);
windowHole.lineTo(-2,0);
windowHole.lineTo(-2,-2);
shape.holes.push(windowHole);

windowHole1 = new THREE.Path();
windowHole1.moveTo(3,3);
windowHole1.lineTo(4,3);
windowHole1.lineTo(4,4);
windowHole1.lineTo(3,4);
windowHole1.lineTo(3,3);
shape.holes.push(windowHole1); 


var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shape );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffccff, side:2, overdraw:true} );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material );
group.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Guess that would help. I added the code to my original post now.

Comment: just check this link...... it will help you... you need to change the order of shape creation..... http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/Vm4kv/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle test code, it's pretty neat. But how do you decide on the order of shape holes? yes reversing the order of holes fixed the problem, but why? how can I tell ahead of time in which order they should be? the users of my software can draw holes anywhere anytime in any order. how should I sort them? Is the order requirement documented anywhere or is this a bug I should report?

Comment: ok I just came up with an example where reversing the order of holes doesn't help. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/runiter/Vm4kv/1/

Comment: perhaps check your path value..It might not be in right order..i have edited my code snippet above.. run on your fiddle. check how the path value have been given, how the hole is create. it may give you some idea...

Comment: check this fiddle also.... [http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/BuNb2/1/]  It will give some fair idea, **do some experiments**.

Comment: somehow my own fiddle no longer exists! do they just erase themselves after an hour? now i can't compare to see what changes you made in your fiddle. Did you change the coordinates?

Comment: you might have your own code, check with it.. just check how the path is ordered.. Imagine how you will draw a rectangle, that's the procedure to give the path coordinates....do some experiment it will give you some idea in it.. If the answer useful  don't forget to accept it.

Comment: you've been very helpful but unfortunately this answer wasn't the correct answer. It turned out the order of path doesn't matter, this was a bug that is fixed now in version 66dev.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on http://learningthreejs.com/data/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/. Whatever your codes are it will help you in doing it better. Substraction, addition, union, intersection everything is possible.

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid subtractions as that's an overkill for my simple shapes. Instead I'm using ShapeGeometry. This is supposed to be a more efficient way with faster processing time, only if it works that is.